# Javascript [data-label] working in Firefox not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, prototype

I'm a designer creating prototypes in Axure, and manipulating its generated html with Javascript in order to demonstrate interaction design. The generated html is constructed largely of `[data-label]` elements, which I have been able to access successfully in my testing in Firefox. Such as:

```
$("div[data-label='ImageDropArea']").append(... etc. ...);
```

While the prototypes work well in Firefox, the Javascript functionality is not working in Chrome and I cannot figure out why. If you visit [This Prototype](http://nickbewley.com/prototypes/freshier-file-upload-with-drag-and-drop/) in Firefox, and click in the image upload area, the images are reflected in the image area below (as in the photo below):

[image]

However, clicking on the image area in chrome does not register the file upload protocol. What could be the difference here? How can I get the functionality to extend to chrome as well as Firefox? I have already spent a lot of time developing these resources in Firefox, and would prefer if I could fix the implementation so that it will work with Chrome / Safari.

For a background of what I am trying to accomplish and the methodology you can [Look Here](http://nickbewley.com/development/hi-er-fidelity-drag-and-drop-file-upload-prototype/). Thanks for any ideas on this vexing issue!

---

EDIT: Adding as recommended by @Marco Bonelli

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
var frameURL = '/prototypes/freshier-file-upload-with-drag-and-drop/',
     pageURL = location.hostname; // www.nickbewley.com or nickbewley.com

document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = 'http://' + pageURL + frameURL;
```

---

EDIT 2: Changing everything to reflect suggestions by @Marco Bonelli (thanks for the help!), but still no luck..

- Put the js file after the iframe
- Added `var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow;` and `iframe.$();`
- Wrapped code in `if (self === parent) { ... }`

Any pointers on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

I worked on your site and I noticed that it actually works fine. I tried to add some event listeners to your ImageDropArea and it worked. Look, try to go to **[YOUR SITE](http://nickbewley.com/development/hi-er-fidelity-drag-and-drop-file-upload-prototype/)**, and copy and paste this code inside the JavaScript console:

```
function handleDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('FILES DROPPED!');
    // do something with the files
    // e.dataTransfer.files
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // say that is a copy
}

dropZone = $('[data-label="ImageDropArea"]')[0];
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

**The above code works fine** for me, and if you drop some file(s) in your drop area it will alert "FILES DROPPED!". So the only thing you have to do now is to do something with the files dropped. You can find them in `e.dataTransfer.files` inside the `drop` handler.

---

By the way **you have to fix this error**, it's very annoying and causes all the code to crash. ***I suggest you to rewrite all your code from zero.***
[image: Error]

Comment: Wow thanks would have never figured that out. But still having a problem. Firefox console reads: `TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined`, and Chrome still is not registering upload dialog either. Thanks for any ideas as to what may be the problem. Really a huge help!

Comment: The first error is probably because you add the script before the iframe. You should add the script after the iframe. If you put the script before the iframe, then, obviously, looking for the iframe (which has not yet been loaded) will fail.

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually it looks like the prototype puts the javascript inside the iframe. Is that something that is workable? Or will I have to figure out an alternate route?

Comment: You can do `if (self === parent) {...}`. If true then you are inside the top frame, the web page. Otherwise you are inside the iframe. You can put all your JS code inside that if-statement so it will not load inside the iframe.

Comment: Wow this is much more difficult than I anticipated. I think I may need some advanced help with this, so will offer a bounty when the time limit expires in a day and a half. It would be awesome if you could help me get this working correctly, as it is way beyond my breadth of knowledge! Thanks for your help so far, however!

Comment: What I don't understand is that I'm using the same method [Here](http://nickbewley.com/prototypes/freshy-file-upload-with-variables/) and it works fine in both Firefox and Chrome.. What could be the difference?

Comment: There is no ImageDrop area here, so you don't use js across the iframe and it works properly.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @Marco Bonelli. I have added a bounty because I need some more information to make the code work. I would greatly appreciate any additional information. Thanks!

Comment: The problem in your page is inside the script fileupload.js, at line 14. That line of code causes an error because the selector returns an empty jQuery object. There is another error in aaxQuery.js in line 205.

Comment: My suggestion is to REMOVE THE IFRAME, because it causes many problems, and do all the work in the page, without frames. Frames are evil. Start doing something easy, like this: http://jsbin.com/zipiqanu/1/edit?js,output and then go ahead and implement more stuff. I can't help you more than this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @Marco Bonelli. I removed the iframe, but strangely am still encountering the same problem. The prototype works in Firefox but not in Chrome. Any idea why that could be? Thanks for your ideas

Comment: First of all, when I put the mouse over your ImageDropArea it gives me a lot of equal errors: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentDynamicPanel' of undefined" at axQuery.js line 205* so first fix this problem. I'm working to see what is going on on your site.

Comment: I EDITED MY ANSWER! Check it out. And you should re-write your question (including the title), because a lot of things changed since you posted it. Moderators may flag it as difficult to understand or something.